# How can I create dynamic graphs in oracle apex?

Tags: graph, charts, oracle-apex

I would like to have only 1 region which should be able to generate more than 1 graphs.

I will have different queries for graphs in table. I will be writing only select statement. based on this, I should be able to generate graphs.

Comment: With a clearer question, I could give a more detailed answer. What is your intent? what have you attempted?

Comment: I want to retrieve graphs from a table like (select graph_name, type from dy_graphs).  I do not want to create regions and keep server side condition for them as I wont be knowing the count of graphs in dy_graphs table.
So, with one region, i should be able to generate more than 1 graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the number of graphs your require at design time, then show/hide the relevant graphs using dynamic actions.

Comment: it should retrieve from the table the number of graphs. I wont be knowing how many graphs will be there in my table.

Comment: Dynamically generating whole regions is not a use case supported by APEX. You will probably need a dynamic plsql region and generate the graphs yourself using Oracle JET.

Comment: And/or rethink the workflow strategy. Seems like an odd scenario.